# In iOS , What's the defference between makeKeyAndVisible and makeKeyWindow+hidden=false?

Tags: ios

I new a window and call function `makeKeyAndVisible()` ,but it don't display .But I call function `makeKeyWindow()` and set `hidden=false` ,it display.

Comment: Why are you making a new window?

Comment: You need to post some code. Preferably a complete working example if it's not too big.